# Delete from patternA to patternB, if it contains patternC within

Tags: awk, sed

Sample input

```
patternA
patternD
patternE
patternB
patternA
patternD
patternC
patternB
```

The output should be

```
patternA
patternD
patternE
patternB
```

The second block of `patternA.....patternB` is deleted because it contains `patternC`

Comment: Sorry, all pattern* should be in seperate lines, not in a single line

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/patternA/!b;:a;N;/patternB/!ba;/patternC/d' file
```

Ignore any lines until `patternA` is encountered. Gather up subsequent lines until the end of the file or `patternB` is encountered. If the gathered up lines contain `patternC` delete them all otherwise print as normal and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/patternA/{f=1; a = $0; next} f{a = a ORS $0} /patternB/{f=0; if(a !~ /patternC/) print a}' file
patternA
patternD
patternE
patternB
```

- Set and unset flag for the start and ending pattern respectively
- When flag is set, accumulate input lines in a variable `a`
- When flag is unset, print contents of `a` if it doesn't contain `patternC`

If input file contains other lines which should be printed, for ex:

```
$ cat file 
foo
patternA
patternD
patternE
patternB
patternA
patternD
patternC
patternB
patternA
pattern1
patternB
bar
baz
```

Then use:

```
$ awk '/patternA/{f=1; a = $0; next} f{a = a ORS $0} /patternB/{f=0; if(a !~ /patternC/) print a; next} !f' file 
foo
patternA
patternD
patternE
patternB
patternA
pattern1
patternB
bar
baz
```

Comment: Hi Sundeep, Thanks for quick response. I tested it and it is working.